# Rotate Images in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js

This will hopefully be a simple question for anyone mildly competent in the CSS that undergirds Quarto presentations (not me). How do I rotate an image? In my fantasy world, something like `![](graphics/statehouse.jpg){.absolute height=300 rotate=30}` would have worked, where `rotate=30` would mean "rotate 30 degrees clockwise." Alas, that does *not* exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with CSS directly,

```
---
title: Rotate Images
format: revealjs
css: style.css
---

## First Slide

::: rotate-img

![](dog.jpg){.absolute height=300}

:::
```

**style.css**

```
.rotate-img img {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

Wrap any image with the pandoc div `rotate-img` to get 40 deg clockwise rotation.